# GPLOAD merges file sometimes when run in parallel threads

Tags: greenplum

So i am running multiple gpload activities in parallel via java code and facing the following problem

First thread calls gpload to load the file : **table1_1234.unl**
Second thread calls gpload to load the file : **table2_5678.unl**

First activity runs without any error and below are the gpload logs

```
2020-05-31 02:00:30|INFO|gpload session started 2020-05-31 02:00:30
2020-05-31 02:01:56|INFO|started gpfdist -p 8081 -P 9081 -f "/data/pathToUnlFiles/340/table1/**table1_1234.unl**" -t 30
2020-05-31 02:03:41|INFO|reusing staging table staging_gpload_reusable_53ec477c694e03c250b2c12f9bb381bd
2020-05-31 02:03:42|INFO|did not find an external table to reuse. creating "gpdb_cards_1240".ext_gpload_reusable_2d9038c6_a31d_11ea_9c16_246e96bddcd8
2020-05-31 02:05:21|INFO|running time: 290.69 seconds
2020-05-31 02:05:21|INFO|rows Inserted          = 0
2020-05-31 02:05:21|INFO|rows Updated           = 8
2020-05-31 02:05:21|INFO|data formatting errors = 0
2020-05-31 02:05:21|INFO|gpload succeeded
```

However the second activity fails with the following logs

```
2020-05-31 02:02:22|INFO|gpload session started 2020-05-31 02:02:22
2020-05-31 02:03:54|INFO|started gpfdist -p 8081 -P 9081 -f "/data/pathToUnlFiles/346/table2/**table2_5678.unl**" -t 30
2020-05-31 02:03:54|INFO|did not find an external table to reuse. creating "gpdb_cards_1246".ext_gpload_reusable_708f2128_a31d_11ea_a649_246e96bddf58
2020-05-31 02:03:55|WARN|8 bad rows
2020-05-31 02:03:55|WARN|Please use following query to access the detailed error
2020-05-31 02:03:55|WARN|select * from gp_read_error_log('"gpdb_cards_1246".ext_gpload_reusable_708f2128_a31d_11ea_a649_246e96bddf58') where cmdtime > to_timestamp('1590915742.6')
2020-05-31 02:03:55|INFO|running time: 92.61 seconds
2020-05-31 02:03:55|INFO|rows Inserted          = 0
2020-05-31 02:03:55|INFO|rows Updated           = 0
2020-05-31 02:03:55|INFO|data formatting errors = 8
2020-05-31 02:03:55|INFO|gpload succeeded with warnings
```

Upon investigating further with the above give query : ( **select * from gp_read_error_log('"gpdb_cards_1246".ext_gpload_reusable_708f2128_a31d_11ea_a649_246e96bddf58') where cmdtime > to_timestamp('1590915742.6'**) , i get the following result

```
cmdtime  | 2020-05-31 02:03:55.087032-07
relname  | ext_gpload_reusable_708f2128_a31d_11ea_a649_246e96bddf58
filename | gpfdist://sgpdbsprlsss:8XX1//data/pathToUnlFiles/346/**table2/table2_5678.unl**/ [/data/pathToUnlFiles/340/**table1/table1_1234.unl**]
linenum  | 1
```

See the column **filename** is showing the filenames of both thread , somehow it is mixing/merging it up.

Any help would be appreciated in this regard as to why GPLOAD utility is behaving like this.

Below is the yaml file

```
VERSION: 1.0.0.1
DATABASE: gpdb
USER: XXXXXX
HOST: xx.xx.xx.xx
PORT: 5432
GPLOAD:
   INPUT:
    - SOURCE:
         LOCAL_HOSTNAME:
           - XXXXXXXXX
         PORT_RANGE: [8081,9081]
         FILE: 
           - /data/pathToUnlFiles/346/table2/table2_5678.unl
    - COLUMNS: 
            - Columns here
    - FORMAT: text
    - DELIMITER: '|'
    - NULL_AS: ''
    - ERROR_LIMIT: 100
    - LOG_ERRORS: true
   EXTERNAL:
    - SCHEMA: '%'
   OUTPUT:
    - TABLE: table2
    - MODE: INSERT
    - MATCH_COLUMNS: 
            - column here
    - UPDATE_COLUMNS: 
            - columns here
   PRELOAD:
    - TRUNCATE: false
    - REUSE_TABLES: true
```

Comment: please share your yml file.

Comment: What part of yaml file would you be interested in ?
As the yaml is created at runtime with filename being replaced with each threads iteration

Comment: I would try setting REUSE_TABLES to false.

Comment: I have added the yaml file above , let me know if there is anything other than REUSE_TABLES flag i need to update
Also we used REUSE_TABLE : true because we set the LOG_ERRORS flag to true as to retain error information.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running gpload parallel, i would check that your java code create yaml with different ports.

Comment: instead of port , we are using port_range option in yaml
i am thinking that might not be the problem here